# Making mypy ignore errors of usages of a specific class method

Tags: python, mypy

I am using a 3rd party Python package which has low-level C bindings and messes the type checks on my code base whenever I use some of the classes from this package. Probably because some methods are created during run-time so they don't exist during static analysis.

For example, there is a class called `Signal` which has methods like `connect()` or `emit()` but using these methods cause mypy to give hundreds of errors like this although the code is working well:

```
...
production_test_window.py:192: error: "Signal" has no attribute "connect"
production_test_window.py:193: error: "Signal" has no attribute "connect"
production_test_window.py:194: error: "Signal" has no attribute "connect"
production_test_window.py:195: error: "Signal" has no attribute "connect"
production_test_window.py:247: error: "Signal" has no attribute "connect"
...
```

As you can see, the errors are happening repeatedly because of the `Signal.connect()` method, although the `connect()` method exists (in run-time). Because I am using this method hundreds of times, I don't want to put `# type: ignore` to each of these lines.

Instead, is there a way to tell mypy to ignore checking method calls of `Signal` class usages of the 3rd party package I am using?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. One option is to add [stub files](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html) declaring classes as if they were python. Another option (if your `Signal` class is already in python, so you want to keep types with code) is [`type_check_only`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.type_check_only) decorator from typing to add this methods with annotations, but mark the method as unavailable. The second option will require some investigations, I'm not sure that it doesn't interfere with C extensions (need to check the implementation).

Comment: @SUTerliakov I don't want to change the files of this 3rd party package because then all users of my code need to do that manually on their machines. Is it possible to create stub files for a 3rd party package but put that stub file on my own project folder?

Comment: Yes! That's how they works (and what they were intended initially for, AFAIR). You'll need to set `MYPYPATH` envvar to point to stubs directory. This directory should represent the structure of original package (or part of it you use). You can start with mypy's `stubgen` tool to create the stubs template and then fix manually missing/incorrect annotations and methods.

Comment: If you end up writing good stubs (at least partially not-`Any` and complete), it would also be great to publish them as a separate package so that others can use it. It should be called `types-{package_name}`, you can look at [`types-requests`](https://pypi.org/project/types-requests/) for reference (it also shows how do stubs for third-party look like in general).